# How to remove “via” and IP when sending mails with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email

When the WordPress sends email (I'm using Godaddy's vps service) it says From correctly but then in gmail it says via `sxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.secureserver.net.` Is there anyway to hide the via part or make it say something like website.com? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it. maybe helping somebody.
Fix the wordpress email return-path header.
Further information: https://abdussamad.com/archives/567-Fixing-the-WordPress-Email-Return-Path-Header.html